# SQL Server 2012 - Synonyms

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, synonym

SQL Server 2005/8 allows you to associate a synonym with a remote table (i.e. a table on a different instance - the reference is via a 4-part name, which includes the link server name).  Does anyone know whether SQL Server 2012 allows a synonym to be directly associated to the Link Server name (rather than a table which exists on the target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Books Online for SQL Server Denali, there appears to be no change in syntax or usage for SYNONYM's.  Probably a safe bet to assume there will be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just duplicate the linked server with your desired new name?
That's not a synonym, but the same server will be available with two names, so in practice they are pretty much the same.

Comment: The issue I have the Dev and UAT database existing on the same SQL Server instance (and hence each points to a different [Dev and UAT resp.] link server).  There are views/stored-procedures that have hardcoded link server names (some via OPENQUERY, some using the 4-part name).  It's not too bad creating synonyms for the 4-part name references but for the OPENQUERY references I need to convert all calls to 4-part names, then use synonyms